# dismissing a GKGameCenterViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been trying without success to dismiss the GKGameCenterViewController view object but it doesn't seem to work;clicking on the done button in game center's view controller seems to do nothining. Below is the code:

```
//Header File:
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Constants.h"
#import "GameManager.h"
#import "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
#import "MenuManager.h"
#import "GamePlayScene.h"

@interface MainMenuLayer : CCLayer {
CCMenu *mainMenu;
CCMenu *sceneSelectMenu;
CCMenu *socialMediaMenu;
}
@end

//View Controller stuff:
@interface myViewController : UIViewController<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>

-(void)displayGameCenter; //called inside the menu layer
-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController    *)gameCenterViewController;
@end


//Implementation file:
#import "MainMenuLayer.h"
#import "GamePlayScene.h"

@implementation myViewController

-(void)displayGameCenter{
UIViewController *rootVC = [UIApplicationsharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController;
gameCenterController= [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

if (gameCenterController != nil)
{
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateDefault;
    [rootVC presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];

    //[self gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:gameCenterController]; }
}        
-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController    *)gameCenterViewController{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

@end
```

Comment: what else have you tried?

Comment: this is very much all that i have tried for now. Please really need help with this. Thanks

Comment: `rootVC` is presenting the controller but `self` is trying to dismiss it.